# Select if exists in part of a column

Tags: mysql, identity-column

I have a table with columns. I'm storing numbers in a `VARCHAR(245)` column. The numbers change all the time. For example, the number can be 42 or 5 or whatever. It can also have multiple numbers, like `42,5,20` and so on.

I want to select if one of the numbers exists and not all. For example, if the numbers are `42,5,20`, I want to select if the number 42 exists in the column, or select if the number 4 or the number 5 appear.

I currently have a query that will select only if there's only one number:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN1='42' AND COLUMN2='1';
```

When there are multiple numbers, the query can't find it.

Comment: Are you able to provide sample data? Also are you wanting it to return say if 42 is in any column and likewise with the other numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking with like-wise operators with multiple checks for an exact value, for the value in between, for the value at the end and at the start.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE (COLUMN1='42' OR COLUMN1 LIKE'%,42,%' OR COLUMN1  LIKE'%,42' OR COLUMN1 LIKE '42,%') AND COLUMN2='1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to solve this. If you use the check for word boundaries you will avoid partial matches.

e.g.

```
mysql> select '42,5,20' REGEXP '[[:<:]]42[[:>:]]' AS 'Found';
+-------+
| Found |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
```

But doesn't find a partial match

```
mysql> select '42,5,20' REGEXP '[[:<:]]2[[:>:]]' AS 'Found';
+-------+
| Found |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
```

This would make your query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE COLUMN1 REGEXP '[[:<:]]42[[:>:]]' 
AND COLUMN2 = '1';
```

Comment: with the upper query it wil find also partical ? like 2 or 4?
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE WHERE (COLUMN1='42' OR COLUMN1 LIKE'%,42,%' OR COLUMN1  LIKE'%,42' OR COLUMN1 LIKE '42,%') AND COLUMN2='1';

Comment: No, the suggestion by @MaxGuarav is perfectly fine because the 4 separate checks cover all the possibilities for a match. I was offering an alternative (and simpler?) solution to the same problem.